# How can I load iOS webclip links in the same window?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, web-clips

After loading up a Webclip with some links in it, clicking a link launches Mobile Safari instead of loading the link in the same window. Is there a way to prevent the link loading in Safari instead of the Webclip instance? I'm trying to mock up a mobile app just using PHP on my local Apache installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#codinghowtos/mobile/userExperience/_index.html) it looks like external page links will always open in Mobile Safari:

> In this mode any external links will be opened in Safari on
>   iPhone, meaning that you will have to keep your web application to a
>   single page and use Ajax to update parts of that page.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the option of using a single page loading new content with AJAX, you can use the JavaScript `self.location=URL; return false` on hyperlinks that must stay within the application.  This can be added to the HTML code directly, or with another script upon loading the page.

If you are using jQuery, I would recommend something like this:

```
$('a:not([target])').click(function(){
    self.location = $(this).attr('href');
    return false;
});
```

Obviously this script should be ran after the HTML has loaded, to ensure that it actually attaches to the `A` elements `onClick` event.